# $f=g \implies \nabla f = \nabla g$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I want to disprove the following statement: $$f=g \text{ on } S \implies \nabla f = \nabla g \text{ on } S$$ where $S$ is some smooth closed surface and $f,g$ are smooth.

I don't understand why this shouldn't be the case, assuming $S$ is more than a single point. In the simplest case, where $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and S is some closed interval this is obviously true ($f'=g'$, right?).
I've tried looking for a relatively simple counterexample (something like $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$) i can plot on geogebra and really see whats going on geometrically, but don't seem to be getting anywhere.

Comment: Doesn't Stokes' theorem help?

Comment: Why do you want to disprove it?

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin I'm sorry i don't see how. Stokes' relates the surface integral of the curl of a vector field to the line integral over the boundary of the vector field, so what would it have to do with my scalar field question?

Comment: @Gibbs It was stated as false in my notes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(x,y):=x$ and $g(x,y):=-x$ in the $(x,y)$-plane, and let $S$ be the $y$-axis. Then $f\restriction S=g\restriction S$, but $\nabla f\restriction S=-\nabla g\restriction S$.

Answer (score 1):

What about the functions $f(r) = r$, and $g(r)= e^{2r-2}$ on the surface $S$, defined by $r=1$.

They take the same value on $S$ ($\textit{i.e.}$ 1) and
\begin{equation}
\nabla f = \vec{e}_r, \qquad \nabla g = 2 e^{2r-2} \vec{e}_r,
\end{equation}

which evaluated on $S$, gives 
\begin{equation}
\nabla f = \vec{e}_r, \qquad \nabla g = 2 \vec{e}_r.
\end{equation}

Comment: If your domain is a circle, it makes no sense to talk about a derivative in the direction of $r$.

Comment: The domain is $\mathbb{R}^2$. I understood the question as the functions being equal on $S$, but not necessarily defined _only_ on $S$.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's how to interpret it, because otherwise the statement is true.